# Generating abbreviations for strings

Tags: algorithm, strings, f#

One of many aspects of a project I am responsible for is generating an abbreviation, that is no more than `n` characters, for a given string. We use this in the organization for a couple things, and it only happens once for each "thing", so performance isn't hyper-critical.

An example is something like "The Main Test Company" — when asking for a 3-character abbreviation, I want to be able to generate a string like `MTC`. Now this would also be the same string as `My Tiny Cat`, but the idea is that a given company *can be abbreviated* and it can be done safely and effectively.

Also, if the abbreviations aren't large enough for the requested characters (say we request 4 characters from `My Awesome Company`) it should, for each abbreviation character, start adding characters to the total (so our example is `MYAC`).

I wrote the whole thing in F#, and it seems pretty readable and followable, I'm also including some test strings to verify functionality. Any comments are welcome.

```
let genAbbr ignoreList padding charCount (str : string) =
    if str.Length <= charCount then
        match padding with
        | Some c -> str |> Seq.append (String(c, charCount - str.Length)) |> Seq.toArray
        | None -> str.ToCharArray()
        |> Array.map Char.ToUpper
        |> String
    else
        let words =
            [|' '|]
            |> Array.append (str.ToCharArray())
            |> Array.fold (fun (acc, cs) c ->
                match c |> Char.IsUpper, c = ' ', cs with
                | true, _, [] -> (acc, [c])
                | true, _, cs -> (cs::acc, [c])
                | _, true, [] -> (acc, [])
                | _, true, cs -> (cs::acc, [])
                | _, _, cs -> (acc, c::cs)) ([], [])
            |> fst
            |> Array.ofList
            |> Array.map (Array.ofList >> Array.rev >> String)
            |> Array.rev
            |> Array.map (fun s -> s.ToCharArray())
        let ignoreWords = words |> Array.filter (fun w -> ignoreList |> Array.contains ((w |> String).ToLower()) |> not)
        let abbrCs =
            if ignoreWords |> Array.length >= charCount then ignoreWords |> Array.map Seq.head
            else if words |> Array.length >= charCount then words |> Array.map Seq.head
            else
                let firstCaps = words |> Array.map (fun s -> if s.Length > charCount then s.[0..charCount] else s) |> Array.length
                printfn "%A %A %A" ignoreWords words firstCaps
                words
                |> Array.fold (fun (acc, r) w ->
                    if w.Length > r then (w.[0..(r - 1)]::acc, 1)
                    else (w::acc, r - (w.Length - 1))) ([], charCount - firstCaps + 1)
                |> fst
                |> Array.ofList
                |> Array.rev
                |> Array.concat
                |> Array.map Char.ToUpper
        abbrCs |> Array.take charCount |> String
```

And lastly, some POC's:

```
["The Main Test Company"; "Main Test Company"; "The Main Company"; "The Company"; "Company"; "MainCompany"; "The MainCompany"; "MainTestCompany"; "SomeRX"; "SomeCompanyT"]
|> List.map (genAbbr [|"the"|] None 3)
// Should be ["MTC"; "MTC"; "TMC"; "THC"; "COM"; "MAC"; "TMC"; "MTC"; "SRX"; "SCT"]
```

Thanks for any commentary, and I look forward to this being brutally decimated. :)

Comment: I took a nap, so my brain is less fried, but still a little fried. I keep trying to follow this code, but all I keep thinking is “Extract functions. Name things.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible improvement points:

- Splitting out functions for word grouping, padding, and word filtering
- Removing unnecessary branching
- Moving from `fold` to self-contained recursive functions that require less post processing
- Use a `HashSet` with a `StringComparer` for filtering

Using these techniques, and avoiding regexes (like my previous answer), we can get a solution that may be easier to reason about:

```
    open System.Collections.Generic

    let getWords (str:string) =
        let word rev_chars = 
            (rev_chars |> List.rev |> Array.ofList |> String).ToUpper()

        let add_word rev_chars acc = 
            if rev_chars <> [] then (word rev_chars) :: acc else acc

        let rec loop (idx:int) (rev_chars:char list) (acc: string list) prev_lower =
            if idx < str.Length then
                let c = str.[idx]
                let rev_chars, acc =
                    match str.[idx] with
                    | ' '                                      -> []             , (add_word rev_chars acc)
                    | c when Char.IsUpper(c)                   -> [c]            , (add_word rev_chars acc)
                    | c                                        -> (c::rev_chars) , acc
                loop (idx + 1) rev_chars acc (Char.IsLower c)
            else
                let acc = add_word rev_chars acc in List.rev acc

        loop 0 [] [] false

    let pad (str:string) len padchar =
        if str.Length < len then str + String(padchar, (len - str.Length)) else str

    // Filter a list of words, if we can 'afford' it, starting from the back    
    let filterWords (ignoreList:HashSet<string>) charCount words =
        let rec loop revWords acc =
            match revWords with
            | [] -> acc
            | word::revWords when ignoreList.Contains(word) ->
                let getLen = List.fold (fun len s -> len + String.length s) 0            
                let maxLenWithout = (getLen words) + (getLen acc)
                let numOtherParts = List.length revWords + List.length acc
                if maxLenWithout >= charCount && numOtherParts >= charCount then loop revWords acc
                else loop revWords (word::acc)
            | word::revWords -> loop revWords (word::acc)

        loop (List.rev words) []

    let genAbbr (ignoreList:HashSet<string>) padding charCount (str : string) =
        let words = getWords str |> filterWords ignoreList charCount

        // Given a list of words, generate a sequence of abbreviations
        let rec abbrs before (words: string list) : string seq = seq {
                match words with
                | [] -> ()
                | word::words ->
                    for i = 1 to word.Length do
                        let before = before + word.Substring(0, i)
                        yield before + (words |> List.map (fun w -> w.Substring(0, 1)) |> String.concat "")
                    yield! abbrs (before + word) words }

        (abbrs "" words)
        |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> s.Length <= charCount)
        |> Seq.maxBy (fun s -> s.Length)
        |> fun s ->
            match padding with | None -> s | Some padchar -> pad s charCount padchar
```

To call it:

```
    let ignored = let h = HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) in h.Add("the") |> ignore; h

    ["The Main Test Company"; "Main Test Company"; "The Main Company"; "The Company"; "Company"; "MainCompany"; "The MainCompany"; "MainTestCompany"; "SomeRX"; "SomeCompanyT"]
    |> List.map (fun w -> w,  (genAbbr ignored None 3 w))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Use `HashSet` with a case insensitive `StringComparer` for the ignore list to reduce case sensitive code `(e.g., Contains(s.ToLower())`
- Use `Regex.Split()` for concision
- Use lazy sequences to generate stream of answers to consider
- Separate some of the steps, so it is easier to reason about
- Look for possibilities to use something other than `FSharp.Core.List`, because having to prepend and then reverse is often accidental rather than essential complexity
- Split out the padding thing to a separate function, since it seems unrelated to abbreviating (not done in code below)

For your consideration:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Collections.Generic

let genAbbr (ignoreList:HashSet<string>) padding charCount (str : string) =
    if str.Length <= charCount then
        str.ToUpper() + 
        match padding with 
        | Some c -> String(Char.ToUpper(c), charCount - str.Length) 
        | None -> ""
    else
        let words = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|\s+")
        let filtered = words |> Array.filter (fun w -> not (ignoreList.Contains(w)))

        if filtered.Length >= charCount then 
            filtered |> Array.map (Seq.head >> Char.ToUpper)|> Array.take charCount |> String
        else if words.Length >= charCount then 
            words |> Array.map Seq.head |> Array.take charCount |> String
        else
            // Expand words with all capital letters
            let words = 
                [ for w in words do
                     if Seq.forall (Char.IsUpper) w then 
                        for c in w do yield String(c, 1)
                     else yield w.ToUpper() ]

            // Given a list of words, generate a sequence of abbreviations
            let rec abbrs before (words: string list) : string seq = seq {
                    match words with
                    | [] -> ()
                    | word::words ->
                        for i = 1 to word.Length do
                            let before = before + word.Substring(0, i)
                            yield before + (words |> List.map (fun w -> w.Substring(0, 1)) |> String.concat "")
                        yield! abbrs (before + word) words }

            (abbrs "" words)
            |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> s.Length <= charCount)
            |> Seq.maxBy (fun s -> s.Length)

let ignored = let h = HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) in h.Add("the") |> ignore; h

["The Main Test Company"; "Main Test Company"; "The Main Company"; "The Company"; "Company"; "MainCompany"; "The MainCompany"; "MainTestCompany"; "SomeRX"; "SomeCompanyT"]
|> List.map (fun w -> w,  (genAbbr ignored None 3 w))
|> fun xs -> xs.Dump()
```

Comment: The only thing about this I don't like is the Regex, but the version I had used code that was just as complex so I suppose I'll live.